# derivative and population mapping

Tags: calculus

The population of graduate students in the northern part of Evanston is given by the formula P(t)=(t^2+100)  ln⁡(t+2), where t represents the time in years since 2000. Using Python, find the rate of change of this population in 2006, as well as the year that the population will reach 500 graduate students.

For the final answer, I got 12ln(8) + 17, and at time t is 10 years. Can someone verify as to this?

Comment: It mentions that you use Python. Does this indicate that a numerical approximated is wanted?

Comment: Without python, would the answer correspond to the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just an idea.*

You know that $P(6)=136 \log (8)\approx 283$ which is not "too" far from the target of $500$.

Develop $P(t)$ as a Taylor series around $t=6$ and get $$P(t)=136 \log (8)+ (17+12 \log (8))(t-6)+ \left(\frac{7}{16}+\log
   (8)\right)(t-6)^2+O\left((t-6)^3\right)$$ Solve the quadratic for $(t-6)$ to get two roots, the positive one corresponding to $$\frac{2 \left(4 \sqrt{2 \left(582-200 \log ^2(8)+1085 \log
   (8)\right)}-47\right)}{7+16 \log (8)}\approx 10.15$$ Now, compute exactly $P(10)=200 \log (12)\approx 497$ while $P(11)=221 \log (13)\approx 567$. So, $t=10$ is your answer.

Otherwise, you could use Newton method to find the zero of $$f(t)=\left(t^2+100\right) \log (t+2)-500$$ $$f'(t)=\frac{t^2+100}{t+2}+2 t \log (t+2)$$ and start the calculations using $t_0=6$. Then, the method will generate the following iterates 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 &  6 \\
 1 & 11.1771 \\
 2 & 10.1067 \\
 3 & 10.0456 \\
 4 & 10.0454 \\
 5 & 10.0450
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P'(t) = 2t \log(t+2) + \frac{t^2+100}{t+2}$$

$$P'(6) = 12\log(8)+17$$
as you found. Then,

$$P(t) = 500$$

and numerically, $t \approx 10$ as you found (i.e. $2010$ is the year that the population is about $500$). There is no elementary closed form solution to this equation.

Comment: shouldn't it be exactly t = 10 since we need years. Or is an approximiation fine if we solve this by hand?

Comment: @amanda The exact number of years is $10.045378\dots$. Indeed, $P(10)=496.9813\dots$. There is no way to express this root using elementary functions. It appears that the question was designed so that this solution would be very close to a round $10$.

Comment: @amanda If what they want to know is simply the year in which the population is $500$, then the number is of course exactly $10$, since the root is slightly more than $10$. This indicates that at some point in the $10$th year, the population will be $500$.